# React & Typescript: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I recently moved from .jsx to .tsx, and I'm having issues (before moving to typescript, was all working well). The first error is at line: "`<Modal show={this.state.isOpen[key]} onClose={this.handleToggleModal.bind(__this,key)}>`". I suspect there's something related to typescript, but I don't know what. Anybody can help me?

```
// TaskCard.tsx

//Dependencies
import * as React from 'react';

//Copmponents
import Modal, {ModalProps} from './Modal';
import Input from './Input';
import {IBoard} from './Board';
import PostComment from './PostComment';

export interface IComments{
    body: string,
    from: string,
    date: string,
    hour: string
}

export interface ITask{
    board: string,
    duedate: string,
    tag: string,
    tagClass: string,
    tagText: string,
    body: string,
    risk: string,
    responsable: string
    comments: IComments[]
}

export interface TaskProps{
    tasks: ITask[]
    boards: IBoard[]
}

export interface TaskState{
    isOpen: {}
}

class TaskCard extends React.Component<TaskProps, TaskState>{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            isOpen: props.isOpen
        };
    }

    handleToggleModal(key) {
        this.state.isOpen[key] = !this.state.isOpen[key];
        this.setState(this.state.isOpen);
    }

    render(){
        const { tasks, boards } = this.props;
        let __this = this;

        return(
            tasks && tasks.map(
                (tasks, key) =>
                <div key={key} className="v-margin no-margin-top card-contour medium" onClick={this.handleToggleModal.bind(__this,key)}>
                    <div className="row middle-xs caption">
                        <div className="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                            <div className="row middle-xs">
                                <img className="img_icn no-padding-left" src="./assets/img/icn_calendar.svg" alt=""/>
                                <p className="txt-tertiary-color">{tasks.duedate}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-6 no-padding">
                            <div className="row end-xs middle-xs">
                                <div className={tasks.tagClass + " tag tag_box center-align"}>
                                    <p>{tasks.tag}</p>
                                    <span className="tag_hint">{tasks.tagText}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row middle-row v-padding">
                        <p>{tasks.body}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row middle-xs caption">
                        <div className="col-xs-9 no-padding">
                            <div className="row middle-xs">
                                <img className="img_icn no-padding-left" src="./assets/img/icn_target.svg" alt=""/>
                                <p className="txt-tertiary-color">Riesgos: {tasks.risk}%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-3 no-padding">
                            <div className="row middle-xs end-xs">
                                <img className="img_icn no-padding-left" src="./assets/img/icn_comments.svg" alt=""/>
                                <p className="txt-tertiary-color">{tasks.comments.length}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Modal show={this.state.isOpen[key]} onClose={this.handleToggleModal.bind(__this,key)}>
                        <div className="modal_container">
                            <section className="modal_section">
                                <div className="row middle-xs no-margin-left no-margin-right modal_section_title">
                                    <object width="20px" height="20px" data="./assets/img/icn_objetive-blue.svg"></object>
                                    <div className="col-xs start-xs">
                                        <h4 className="semi-bold">Objetivo</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-xs-12 modal_section_content">
                                    <p>{tasks.body}</p>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                            <section className="modal_section">
                                <div className="row middle-xs no-margin-left no-margin-right modal_section_title">
                                    <object width="20px" height="20px" data="./assets/img/icn_target-blue.svg"></object>
                                    <div className="col-xs start-xs">
                                        <h4 className="semi-bold">Target</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-xs-12 modal_section_content">
                                    <p>Riesgos / Problemas = {tasks.risk}%</p>
                                    <div className="table v-margin">
                                        <div className="row middle-xs">
                                            <div className="col-xs">
                                                <p className="table_head">Fecha de vencimiento</p>
                                                <p className="table_body">{tasks.duedate}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-xs">
                                                <p className="table_head">Tipo de objetivo</p>
                                                <p className="table_body">{tasks.tagText}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-xs">
                                                <p className="table_head">Responsable</p>
                                                <p className="table_body">{tasks.responsable}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-xs-12 v-margin no-margin-bottom">
                                                <p className="table_head">Estado de objetivo</p>
                                                <div className="row middle-xs">
                                                    {
                                                        boards && boards.map(
                                                        (boards, board) =>
                                                        <div key={board} className="col-xs-3">
                                                            <Input name="state" type="radio" classNameCustom="input_radio"
                                                            checked={boards.id == tasks.board} value={boards.id} id={boards.id}/>
                                                            <label htmlFor={boards.id}>{boards.name}</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                            <section className="modal_section">
                                <div className="row middle-xs no-margin-left no-margin-right modal_section_title">
                                    <object width="20px" height="20px" data="./assets/img/icn_activity-blue.svg"></object>
                                    <div className="col-xs start-xs">
                                        <h4 className="semi-bold">Actividad</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-xs-12 modal_section_content">
                                    {
                                        tasks.comments.length!=0 ?(
                                            tasks.comments.map((comments, i) => {
                                                return(
                                                    <div key={i} className="comment">
                                                        <div className="comment_box">
                                                            <p>{comments.body}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="comment_data row no-margin middle-xs">
                                                            <div className="col-xs start-xs">
                                                                <p>{comments.from}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-xs end-xs">
                                                                <p>{comments.date} a las {comments.hour} hs.</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                )
                                            })
                                        ):null                                
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <PostComment />
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            )
        )
    }
}

export default TaskCard;
```

And here is the Modal component

```
//Modal.tsx file
//Dependencies
import * as React from 'react';

export interface ModalProps{
    onClose: any,
    show: boolean,
    children: any
}

export default class Modal extends React.Component<ModalProps>{
    handleStopPropagation = (e) =>{
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    render(){
        const {onClose, show, children} = this.props;

        // Render nothing if the "show" prop is false
        if(!this.props.show) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div className="modal_bkg" onClick={this.handleStopPropagation}>
                <div className="modal_bkg_container row middle-xs center-xs">
                    <div className="modal card">
                        <div className="right-align modal_close">
                            <button className="btn btn_close" onClick={this.props.onClose}>x</button>
                        </div>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: your handler function. `handleToggleModal(key)` should be `handleToggleModal = (key) => {` that way you can remove the `__this`

Comment: also.. it sounds like you are importing something incorrectly. Make sure you have typings for all of your packages and that you are importing correctly (aka default as opposed to named as opposed to `import * as asdf from `)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me with this and now it's working. The first problem was the state "isOpen" at start always is undefined so, that's why runtime was throwing error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". So now, "isOpen" is and empty object and the final constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
        isOpen: {}
    };
}
```

After this, another error was "boards.map is not a function" and that was because I was passing the array "boards" as object. Changing for "board" was enought. So the final code was:

```
boards && boards.map(
    (board, key) =>
    <div key={key} className="col-xs-3">
       <Input name="state" type="radio" classNameCustom="input_radio"
       checked={board.id == task.board} value={board.id} id={board.id}/>
       <label htmlFor={board.id}>{board.name}</label>
    </div>
)
```

Anyway, thanks for trying to help me. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to run the code at the moment, but as far as I can see the `TaskCard.render` function is using `Array.map` function, which is executing a callback function for every task item.

And there is a problem, because in the callback `this` is not the `this` you think it is :). According to documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map you can use map overload that accepts `this`.

I believe that if you do

```
return(tasks && tasks.map(
            (tasks, key) => <div>put your component markup here</div>,
            this)
      );
```

inside `TaskCard.render` function you should see the error no more.

Comment: When I try to use spread operator as you comment, VSCode throws an error saying "expression expected".

Comment: Sorry for confusion, its not a spread operator as it may look at first sight, those three dots are just a placeholder for your TaskCard component markup. I will update my answer to avoid future confusion.